# Is there a trigger I can use if a fallback font is used in CSS?

Tags: css, font-face

I'm using [this service](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator) to create `@font-face` rules in my CSS. What I've done is created two rules, one for the normal weight font and another for the bold weight version. Like so:

```
@font-face
{
    font-family: 'CenturyGothicRegular';
    src: url('/static/fonts/gothic_2-webfont.eot');
    src: url('/static/fonts/gothic_2-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
          url('/static/fonts/gothic_2-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
          url('/static/fonts/gothic_2-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
          url('/static/fonts/gothic_2-webfont.svg#CenturyGothicRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
... and another for 'CenturyGothicBold'
```

I've then made the overall font for my site default back to Verdana like so:

```
body
{
    font-family: "CenturyGothicRegular", Verdana;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

And made a little rule for `<strong>` so that rather than making the normal weight version bold (which just seems to stretch it), the bold weight version will be used:

```
strong
{
    font-weight: normal;
    font-family: 'CenturyGothicBold';
}
```

An issue I can foresee here is that if the font has defaulted to Verdana, bold won't be present.

Is there a way that I can specify a new set of rules for `<strong>` that only apply if the font has defaulted to Verdana?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to find a trigger to see if a fall back font has been used.

What you need to do is set the the `font-weight` in the `@font-face` rule, using the same family name. So you would now call it *CenturyGothic*:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'CenturyGothic'; /* this used to be CenturyGothicRegular */
    src: url('/static/fonts/gothic_2-webfont.eot');
    src: url('/static/fonts/gothic_2-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('/static/fonts/gothic_2-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('/static/fonts/gothic_2-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('/static/fonts/gothic_2-webfont.svg#CenturyGothicRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'CenturyGothic'; /* this used to be CenturyGothicBold but the urls still need to point to the files they were pointing at */
    src: url('/static/fonts/gothic_2-webfont.eot');
    src: url('/static/fonts/gothic_2-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('/static/fonts/gothic_2-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('/static/fonts/gothic_2-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('/static/fonts/gothic_2-webfont.svg#CenturyGothicRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: bold;
}

body{
    font-family: "CenturyGothic", Verdana;
    font-size: 14px;
}

strong{
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

This will combine the two fonts into one `font-family` allowing it to act like any other `font-family` i.e. when you make it `bold` it will display the bold version of the font etc.

Comment: @marty: Let me know if this needs more explanation.

Comment: Looks good to me, just give me a chance to implement this and I'll get back to you :)

Comment: Blackmail.. ( Anyone who can read this message, if you dont hear from me. tw16 did it. ) ..and theres your +1.. :)

Comment: And now i play the waiting game.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Using `font-weight` only with the same `font-family` will not work when you have several `weight`, like Light, ultralight, condensed bold, demi bold etc.